# Populating list views with child list items from input xml in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following thing to achieve in Android(newbie). I have an xml which has contents in this format

```
<xml>
<parent id = 1 Name = "Cat" >
  <child id = 3>
  <child id = 4>
</parent>
<child id=3 Name = "Video">
  <raw id =6>
</child>
<child id=4 Name = "Text">
  <raw id =7>
</child>
<raw id=6 destination="www.cat.com">
</raw>
<raw id=7 destination="www.cat.pdf">
</raw>
</xml>
```

So basically i want one screen to show parent ids in our case "CAT". On clicking CAT, it has to move to the next screen which shows the children of CAT which is "Video" and "Text".
On clicking Video it has to play video from the mention location. How do I achieve this. Please help.

Comment: Also is this possible using listviews? Expandable list views support only two levels, but in my case I might more levels. I tried the tree view from google code suggested but its not for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up putting the xml data into a sqlite database and using a cursor adapter to feed listviews to populate lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate "string.xml -> array" with yours items,

**So basically i want one screen to show parent ids in our case "CAT". On clicking CAT, it has to move to the next screen which shows the children of CAT which is "Video" and "Text". On clicking Video it has to play video from the mention location. How do I achieve this. Please help.**

The first activity you implement this:

```
String[] parent= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, parent));
```

You can learn about it on the [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

Comment: Thanks Franklin, I understand the logic of parsing the xml and putting the data into strings.xml. But I am not sure how I can relate them across activities. For instance I create a list for CAT. On clicking Cat it has to move to an activity which says Video and Text and so on based on the relationship in the XML